# String formatting: preserve all digits before point, but truncate after point

Tags: c#, string-formatting

How do I format this number in the following way?

The digits before the point should be preserved, but the digits after the point should be truncated to the first three digits.

Example:

```
double example1 = 0.7221025; // Wanted: 0.722
double example2 = 1.2300001; // Wanted: 1.230
double example3 = 1.000000001; // Wanted: 1.000
```

I have tried using String.Format, but I have trouble getting the correct formatter.

Answer (score 2):

you can use number.ToString("0.000"):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Double_ToString_System_String_

Answer (score 0):

if you are insisting to use

> String.Format

Then you can use it like this example:

```
String.Format("{0:0.000}", example1)
```